# Make links work in backup?

Tags: rsync, backup, symlink

One file system of mine has many symlinks which link to directories in the file system.

Is it possible to create a backup of the file system where the backups of the links work (i.e. still point to the correct directories in the backup of a file system)? I currently use `rsync` for creating backup. Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for `-l` option which means *copy symlinks as symlinks*. Another, even better option in your case is `-a` (`--archive` mode), which is equivalent of `-rlptgoD` (basically preserves everything - *links, permissions, etc*). Run `man rsync`, there are a lot of useful examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to copy *relative* symlinks using `--links` option:

> ```
>    -l, --links
>           When symlinks are encountered, recreate the symlink on the
>           destination.
> ```

Also:

> Note that --archive implies --links.

Example:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/tarsnap-test/
$ cd /tmp/tarsnap-test/
$ mkdir orig backup
$ cd orig/
$ mkdir dir
$ ln -s dir symlink
$ ll
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 ja ja 4.0K Mar  4 14:26 dir
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ja ja    3 Mar  4 14:26 symlink -> dir
$ cd ../backup/
$ rsync -avz  /tmp/tarsnap-test/orig/ .
sending incremental file list
./
symlink -> dir
dir/

sent 88 bytes  received 22 bytes  220.00 bytes/sec
total size is 3  speedup is 0.03
$ ll
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 ja ja 4.0K Mar  4 14:26 dir
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ja ja    3 Mar  4 14:26 symlink -> dir
```

However, it is not possible to copy absolute symlinks using rsync. If an original directory that contains an absolute symlink is copied into a destination directory symlink still points to the original filesytem. You can use `symlinks` tool to clean up this mess.

Comment: Thanks. How do you use symlinks tool to clean up this mess? I have lots of symlinks that uses absolute paths, and want to make them work again as automatically as possible by scripting.